# How to display rows in listview According to Date Cell Ascending in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to display items in Listview in xamarin forms according to Date cell in Ascending order.

```
<ListView
  x:Name="ExpiryProductsData"
  SelectionMode="Single"
  GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding ExpiryDate}"
  SeparatorColor="LightGray"
  SeparatorVisibility="Default">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout
                VerticalOptions="Center">
                <DatePicker
                    Date ="{Binding ExpiryDate}"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    DateSelected="DatePicker_DateSelected"
                    PropertyChanged="DatePicker_PropertyChanged"
                    Format="yyyy-MM-dd">
                </DatePicker>
              </StackLayout>
           </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Sort the ItemsSource data by date first

Comment: How to sort it ?

Comment: There are numerous existing questions about sorting data in C#

Comment: It did n't help a lot. I only know there are  numerous existing questions about sorting data in C#

Comment: Please be specific about what you’ve tried and what problems or errors you’re encountering.  Your post doesn’t contain any details about your data, just UI

Comment: I already solved this by myself